# PROBLEMA AO CLICAR COM UM ROBÔ USANDO PUPPETEER

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Eu estou criando este robô para automatizar algumas tarefas do eu dia a dia, eu peço para ele acessar o site, clicar no input, e depois logar. Ele acessa a pagina, Mas ele não está clicando, não consigo achar o problema. este é o código

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () =>{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const site = 'http://www.goolsystem.com.br';
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://www.goolsystem.com.br/4/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f4');
    await page.waitFor('#ucTrocarModulo_btnIconeUrbano > input');
    await page.click('#ucTrocarModulo_btnIconeUrbano > input');
    await page.type('input[name="ucLogarUsuario$txtLogin"]','@@@@@', {delay: 100});
    await page.type('input[name="ucLogarUsuario$txtSenha"]', '@@@@@', {delay: 100});
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter');

    await browser.close();
})();
```

quando eu executo mostra o seguinte erro: "(node:5920) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5920) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will
terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seletor do input que deseja clicar esta errado, o id do seletor pai é `ucTrocarModulo_moduloUrbano` e você esta utilizando o id do seletor filho que é `ucTrocarModulo_btnIconeUrbano` (o input) e tentando buscar um input dentro do mesmo, ou seja, você esta tentando clicar um input dentro do input que você quer clicar, como não existe ele apresenta o erro.

Opções corretas:

1 - `#ucTrocarModulo_moduloUrbano > input`

2 - `#ucTrocarModulo_moduloUrbano #ucTrocarModulo_btnIconeUrbano`

3 - `#ucTrocarModulo_btnIconeUrbano`

Você pode utilizar o ID do elemento diretamente (como na opção 3). Tente isso:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () =>{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const site = 'http://www.goolsystem.com.br';
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://www.goolsystem.com.br/4/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f4');
    await page.waitFor('#ucTrocarModulo_btnIconeUrbano'); // ID do input
    await page.click('#ucTrocarModulo_btnIconeUrbano'); // ID do input
    await page.waitFor('#ucLogarUsuario_txtLogin'); 
    await page.type('#ucLogarUsuario_txtLogin','@@@@@', {delay: 100}); // ID do input Login
    await page.type('#ucLogarUsuario_txtSenha', '@@@@@', {delay: 100}); // ID do senha
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter');

    await browser.close();
})();
```